# Maximum of the ratio of some moments of a non-negative random variable

Tags: probability, measure-theory

What is $$\sup_X \frac{\mathbb  E(X^3)\mathbb  E(X)}{(\mathbb  E(X^2))^2}$$ for X a non-negative random variable? I think the min is reached in Dirac masses, but for the max I don't find it.

Comment: The minimum is $1$ (see the [Stieltjes moment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_moment_problem)) and clearly achieved when $P(X=c)=1$ for any $c>0$.  The supremum is infinite: consider a random variable with $P(X>x)=x^{-3}$ for $x \ge 1$

Comment: Thanks ThanksThanks